# Laravel : how to get list of items from a category

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently developing a website using laravel

I'm trying to create a registration form with a category in it, it's a motorcycle brand category

The category has :
Honda
Yamaha
Kawasaki
Suzuki

And from each of that category has it's own :

Honda has :
Supra X
Supra X 125 Tromol

Yamaha has :
JUPITER
JUPITER Z

Kawasaki has :
ZX CW/VR
ZONE R/VR

Suzuki has :
SHOGUN 125
New SHOGUN 125

The input of the registration page is consist of

Name

Motorcycle brand(in a form of listbox)

Motorcycle name(in a form of listbox)

The problem : when i input the motorcycle brand like "honda", it should be showing the list of motorcycle from "honda" category.

Instead it shows the list of motorcycle from "suzuki" list. So it's got the last ID from the list :
SHOGUN 125
New SHOGUN 125

How do i solve this problem??

The motorcycle brand table :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('motorcycle_brands', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('motorcycle_brand_name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

The motorcycle table :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('motorcycles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('motorcycle_brand_id')->references('id')->on('motorcycle_brands');
            $table->string('motorcycle_name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

The motorcycle model :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Motorcycle extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'motorcycle_brand_id',
        'motorcycle_name'
    ];

    public function motorcycle(){
        return $this->hasMany(Motorcycle::class, 'motorcycle_brand_id');
    }

    public function motorcycle_brand(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Motorcycle::class, 'motorcycle_brand_id');
    }
}
```

The controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\MotorcycleBrand;
use App\Models\Motorcycle;
use App\Models\Kredit;

class MotorCycleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $kredits = Kredit::all();
        return view('kredit', ['kredits'=>$kredits, 'layout'=>'index']);
        //
    }

    public function motorcycle_brand()
    {
        $kredits = Kredit::where('motorcycle_brand_id', '=', $id)->get();
        $motorcycle_brands = MotorcycleBrand::where('id', '=', $id)->first();
        return view('motorcycle_brand', ['kredits'=>$kredits, 'motorcycle_brands'=>$motorcycle_brands]);
    }

    public function motorcycle()
    {
        $kredits = Kredit::where('motorcycle_id', '=', $id)->get();
        $motorcycles = Motorcycle::where('motorcycle_id', '=', $id)->first();
        return view('motorcycle', ['kredits'=>$kredits, 'motorcycles'=>$motorcycles]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $kredits = Kredit::all();
        $motorcycle_brands = MotorcycleBrand::all();
        $motorcycles = Motorcycle::all();
        return view('createkredit', ['kredits'=>$kredits, 'motorcycle_brands'=>$motorcycle_brands, 
        'motorcycles'=>$motorcycles, 'layout'=>'create']);
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $kredit = new Kredit();
        $kredit->motorcycle_brand_id = $request->input('motorcycle_brand');
        $kredit->motorcycle_id = $request->input('motorcycle');
        $kredit->name = $request->input('name');

        $kredit->save();
        return redirect('/kredit');
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $kredit = Kredit::find($id);
        $kredits = Kredit::all();
        return view('kreditlist', ['kredit'=>$kredit, 'kredits'=>$kredits, 'layout'=>'show']);
        //
    }
}
```

The create blade.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width= <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card mx-auto" style="width: 40rem">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <center>Form Pengajuan Kredit Motor</center>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <section class="col">
                            <form class="contact-form" action="{{url('/store')}}" method="POST">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Nama Lengkap</label>
                                    <input type="text" required class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="{{old('name')}}" placeholder="Contoh : Nathanael Budiman">
                                </div>
                                @error('name') 
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                                @enderror
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="motorcycle_brand">Brand Motor</label>
                                    <input type="text" required class="form-control @error('motorcycle_brand') is-invalid @enderror" list="motorcycle_brandList" id="motorcycle_brand" name="motorcycle_brand" autocomplete="off" value="{{old('motorcycle_brand')}}" placeholder="Contoh : Honda">
                                    <datalist id="motorcycle_brandList" name="motorcycle_brand">
                                        @foreach ($motorcycle_brands as $motorcycle_brand)
                                            <option value="{{$motorcycle_brand->motorcycle_brand_name}}">{{$motorcycle_brand->motorcycle_brand_name}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </datalist>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="motorcycle">Brand Motor</label>
                                    <input type="text" required class="form-control @error('motorcycle') is-invalid @enderror" list="motorcycleList" id="motorcycle" name="motorcycle" autocomplete="off" value="{{old('motorcycle')}}" placeholder="Contoh : Honda">
                                    <datalist id="motorcycleList" name="motorcycle">
                                        @foreach ($motorcycles as $motorcycle)
                                            @if ($motorcycle->motorcycle_brand_id == $motorcycle_brand->id)
                                                <option value="{{$motorcycle->motorcycle_name}}">{{$motorcycle->motorcycle_name}}</option>
                                            @endif
                                        @endforeach
                                    </datalist>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="btn_submit" 
                                style="background-color: #ffc107; border:none; color:black">Ajukan Kredit</button>
                            </form>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, you can achieve this populating dynamically the second list...for example you can set an onChange event on the first list ( the Manufacturer list ) passing a manufacturer to JS wherewith you populate the second list

Comment: Hello. Is there another wat to do it?? Like using eloquent relationship or we have to use JS for this one to work??

Comment: In my opinion the most effective and fastest way to get what you are looking for is by using JS

Comment: Owh i see. Thank you for your help. I will try this method

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement correct relation between you models.
Its *OneToMane* relation, because One Brand can have many motorcycles, but motorcycle belongs to only one.

*for Motorcycle model:*

```
class Motorcycle extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'motorcycle_brand_id',
        'motorcycle_name'
    ];


    public function motorcycleBrand(){
        return $this->belongsTo(MotorcycleBrand::class, 'motorcycle_brand_id');
    }
}
```

*for MotorcycleBrand model:*

```
class MotorcycleBrand extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'motorcycle_brand_name'
    ];


    public function motorcycles(){
        return $this->hasMany(Motorcycle::class, 'motorcycle_brand_id');
    }
}
```

Now You can get parent in Motorcycle model, f.e. name of brand:

```
$motorcycleBrandName = Motorcycle::find(1)->motorcycleBrand()->motorcycle_brand_name;
```

And on the other side, get all motorcycles which belong to brand:

```
$motorcycles = MotorcycleBrand::find(1)->motorcycles();
```

To update input with motorcycles while choosing brand, you can user ajax, read more here https://larainfo.com/blogs/laravel-select-categories-to-subcategories-using-jquery-ajax

**And the last thing: Please use camelCase for naming properties and methods**